# Как сделать код рекурсивным?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```
const data = [
  { itemId: 1, itemName: "пункт №1", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 2, itemName: "пункт №1.1", itemParentId: 1 },
  { itemId: 3, itemName: "пункт №1.2", itemParentId: 1 },
  { itemId: 4, itemName: "пункт №1.2.1", itemParentId: 3 },
  { itemId: 5, itemName: "пункт №1.2.2", itemParentId: 3 },
  { itemId: 6, itemName: "пункт №1.2.3", itemParentId: 3 },
  { itemId: 7, itemName: "пункт №2", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 8, itemName: "пункт №3", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 9, itemName: "пункт №3.1", itemParentId: 8 },
  { itemId: 10, itemName: "пункт №3.2", itemParentId: 8 },
  { itemId: 11, itemName: "пункт №3.3", itemParentId: 8 },
  { itemId: 12, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1", itemParentId: 11 },
  { itemId: 13, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.1", itemParentId: 12 },
  { itemId: 14, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.2", itemParentId: 12 },
  { itemId: 15, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.3", itemParentId: 12 },
  { itemId: 16, itemName: "пункт №3.3.2", itemParentId: 11 },
  { itemId: 17, itemName: "пункт №4", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 18, itemName: "пункт №5", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 19, itemName: "пункт №5.1", itemParentId: 18 }
]

function parseList(data) {
    data.reduce((acc, current, i, source) => {
        const $li = document.createElement('li')
    $li.textContent = current.itemName
    
    acc[current.itemParentId].children[0].appendChild($li)
    
    if (source[i + 1] && source[i + 1].itemParentId === current.itemId) {
      const $ul = document.createElement('ul') 
      $li.appendChild($ul)
    }
    
    acc[i + 1] = $li
    
    return acc
  }, { 0: { children: [document.querySelector('ul')] } })
}

parseList(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно так

```js
const data = [
  { itemId: 1, itemName: "пункт №1", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 2, itemName: "пункт №1.1", itemParentId: 1 },
  { itemId: 3, itemName: "пункт №1.2", itemParentId: 1 },
  { itemId: 4, itemName: "пункт №1.2.1", itemParentId: 3 },
  { itemId: 5, itemName: "пункт №1.2.2", itemParentId: 3 },
  { itemId: 6, itemName: "пункт №1.2.3", itemParentId: 3 },
  { itemId: 7, itemName: "пункт №2", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 8, itemName: "пункт №3", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 9, itemName: "пункт №3.1", itemParentId: 8 },
  { itemId: 10, itemName: "пункт №3.2", itemParentId: 8 },
  { itemId: 11, itemName: "пункт №3.3", itemParentId: 8 },
  { itemId: 12, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1", itemParentId: 11 },
  { itemId: 13, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.1", itemParentId: 12 },
  { itemId: 14, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.2", itemParentId: 12 },
  { itemId: 15, itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.3", itemParentId: 12 },
  { itemId: 16, itemName: "пункт №3.3.2", itemParentId: 11 },
  { itemId: 17, itemName: "пункт №4", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 18, itemName: "пункт №5", itemParentId: 0 },
  { itemId: 19, itemName: "пункт №5.1", itemParentId: 18 }
]


function parseList(data, acc) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    let current  = data.shift();
    const $li = document.createElement('li');
    $li.textContent = current.itemName;
    
    acc[current.itemParentId].children[0].appendChild($li);
    
    if (data[0] && data[0].itemParentId === current.itemId) {
      const $ul = document.createElement('ul') 
      $li.appendChild($ul)
    }
    
    acc[current.itemId] = $li;
    parseList(data, acc);
  }
}

parseList(data, { 0: document.querySelector('div')})
```

```html
<div><ul></ul></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если ни секрет какой у тебя уровень синьор или мидл ?

Comment: секрета нет - архитектор

Comment: @jora я бы конечно реализовал это по другому. Но реализовал Ваш вариант через рекурсию

Comment: это выше синьора ?

Comment: Да немного, совсем чуточку :))